# Execute powershell script on a "selected" item in a sharepoint list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I hope this is a straightforward question and it gets received and answered quickly without prejudice of any kind as I am fairly new to this of kind coding.  Every powershell code snippet I see points to running code on an entire sharepoint list. What I need is to run the powershell code that runs on a selected list item.

I often see code similar to below that only handles the entire list:

```
$list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
```

or

```
$items = $list.Items
```

If it is not possible to do this and interrogate a specific list item that is "selected", then I'll try to find another way. If there is a method, cmdlet, or cmdlet switch that does this, it eludes me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am creating a custom action that copies selected items in a sharepoint online site list over to different sharepoint online site list. I want to do this with the reference ID in tact so that the list items on both sites contain the same reference ID.  I know how to copy an entire list but have seen none for "selected" Items.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to check within the HTML of the page for each of the list items.
Generally, items with a checkbox in HTML have an attribute like "checked", so you could use the `where` operator to search the html for it.

Ex.

```
$pageData = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://yoursharepointsite.example/yourlistpage"
$checkedItems = $pageData | ? {$_.type -eq "input" -and $_.checked} | Select-Object
```

Apologies that I can't remember the exact syntax, but to get every input item I think you could use the .GetElementById() or GetElementsByTagName() methods against the DOM, then store in a list every checked element, then loop through moving each item.

Hope that helps if anything at least conceptually.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a great idea. I look for the "checked attribute" in the page and try that.